# How can I load require.js from multiple paths, without using an absolute url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs

I have a directory structure like this:

```
├── index.html
├── static
│   └── js
│       ├── main.js
│       ├── jquery.js
│       └── require.js
└── subfolder
    └── index.html
```

In my top-level `index.html`, I'm loading require.js like this, and it works:

```
<script data-main="static/js/main" src="static/js/require.min.js"></script>
```

However, in `subfolder/index.html`, I can't load require.js succesfully:

```
<script data-main="../static/js/main" src="../static/js/require.min.js"></script>
```

Which results in "Script error for: jquery", and the same for each dependency of my `main` module.

The `baseUrl` for require.js is set to `static/js`. Because these pages are intended to be used locally, I can't use an absolute url. How can I get require.js to work from the subfolders?

Contents of the main.js file:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'static/js',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery-2.0.3',
    }
});

require(['jquery'], function($) { ... }
```

Comment: show your main.js file.

Comment: have you tried `baseUrl: '../static/js'`?

Comment: If I did that, then the top-level `index.html` would stop working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to not set `baseUrl` at all:

> If no baseUrl is explicitly set in the configuration, the default value will be the location of the HTML page that loads require.js. If a data-main attribute is used, that path will become the baseUrl.

Removing the `baseUrl` setting resulted in the above example working correctly.